# Not found error while calling apicontroller from angularjs file

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am building an application with the following flow 
  My Controller will call the View. Inside the view i am calling a js file which has angularjs code with makes a call to the APIController.

I am getting the following error :

```
Request URL:http://localhost:52096/api/EVerify/GetEmployeeList
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

What am i missing or doing wrong.

Controller :

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVC.EVerify.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class EVerifyController : Controller
    {
        #region Methods
        #region ListEVerify
        public ActionResult ListEVerify()
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) return PartialView();
            return View();
        }
        #endregion
}
```

View :

In this view on click of a button I am loading another view along with Javascript file which has angular code called EverifyModule.js

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="emp in EmployeeInfo">
      <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
       <td>{{emp.hireDate}}</td>
       <td><a class="btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="LoadViewSelected('/EVerify/EVerify/EVerifySubmit', 'EVerifyModule', 'E-VerifySubmit');">E-Verify</a></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

EVerifyModule.js

```
var EVerifyModule = angular.module('EVerifyModule', ['angularFileUpload', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);


    EVerifyModule.factory('EVerifyModuleService', ['$http', '$window', function ($http, $window) {

        return {

            GetEmployeeList: function (companyId) {
                return $http({
                    url: '/api/EVerify/GetEmployeeList',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: companyId
                });
            }
        };
    }]);


    EVerifyModule.controller('EVerifyController', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', 'EVerifyModuleService', '$modal', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $compile, EVerifyModuleService, $modal, $timeout) {

        EVerifyModuleService.GetEmployeeList(58).then(function (response) {
            $scope.EmployeeInfo = response.data.Employees;
        });
```

EVerifyAPIController :

```
namespace MVC.EVerify.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/EVerify")]
    public class EVerifyAPIController : ApiController
    {
        #region GetEmployeeList

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("GetEmployeeList")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetEmployeeList(int CompanyId)
        {
            List<EmployeeBO> employees = new List<EmployeeBO>();

            try
            {
                employees = await EmployeeBL.GetEmployeeList(CompanyId);
            }
            catch
            {
                employees = new List<EmployeeBO>();
            }

            return Ok(new { Employees = employees });
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Model Binder expects your `CompanyId` parameter to be placed in the URI, but you are sending it inside the request body.

Explicitly tell your action method that you are sending the parameter in the body:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetEmployeeList([FromBody] int CompanyId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the GetEmployeeList method takes in a parameter so maybe you just need to pass it a parameter? Like:
`http://localhost:52096/api/EVerify/GetEmployeeList/1`

Comment: When I test this using an API client I am getting the following error : {
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:52096/api/EVerify/GetEmployeeList'."
"MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'EVerifyAPI' that matches the request."
}